# AngularJS : How to prevent a request

Tags: angularjs, request

Is it possible to prevent a request using angularjs interceptors ?

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, someService) {
  return {
    'request': function(config) {
      // here I'd like to cancel a request depending of some conditions
    }
  }
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In 1.1.5 and later you can use the 'timeout' property of the configuration object.

From the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#usage):

> timeout – {number|Promise} – timeout in milliseconds, or promise that
>   should abort the request when resolved.

Simple example:

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, someService) {
  return {
    'request': function(config) {

        var canceler = $q.defer();

        config.timeout = canceler.promise;

        if (true) {

            // Canceling request
            canceler.resolve();
        }

        return config;
    }
  }
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the line `return config || $q.when(config);` does ? Or rather: how can `config` evaluate to false - the code above that line assume that it is a valid config object ?

Comment: You are correct. It should just be `return config`, since `config.timeout = canceler.promise;` wouldn't work if `config` is `undefined` anyway. I was sloppy and took the code from the old interceptor documentation, which only contains the line `return config || $q.when(config);` and added some logic above it. I will edit it. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I apply this logic which is working:

```
$scope.cancelRequest = 0;               // initilize taking variable
$scope.searchUser = function() {
    $scope.cancelRequest = 0;           // initilize taking variable
    var opts = {};
    $scope.userList = [];               //array in witch i store the list
    if($scope.searchFrind != ""){       // checking the value of the model is blank or their is some data
        opts.limit_size = 10; 
        ProfileService.searchUser(opts, function(data) {   // calling the service which call the http request
            if( $scope.cancelRequest == 0 ){    // checking the value of cancelRequest as if the request is late and we doesnot want it then it fall in the else case
                angular.forEach(data.data.users,function(user) {
                    $scope.userList.push(user);
                })
            }else{                          //when the cancelRequest is notequal 0 then this part run
                $scope.userList = [];       //empty the array
            }
        });
    }else{
        $scope.userList = [];
        $scope.cancelRequest = 1; //changing the value of cancelRequest to 1 so that the pending http request  after completion does not disturb the array or any model
    }
};
```

Comment: You're still making an actual HTTP request (and discarding its response, resulting in useless server load), which is not desired by OP.