# Is it possible to check condition before all http calls in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

Is it possible to check if: `$rootScope.variable is TRUE`

Before all `$http` calls are called, or I should check for every individual call? Some of my calls are call through angular `factory`, and some are not.

I thought there is maybe some way like httpInterceptor which would check before some call is ran.

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: you should use promise chain using `.then()` to maintain proper call stack, by calling one after another

Comment: _"Some of my calls are call through angular factory, and some are not. "_ Well, why not make a factory that does this check and then consistently use that? That would clearly convey what is going on rather than having surprises happening in an httpInterceptor.

Comment: *I thought there is maybe some way like httpInterceptor*: good thought. Why don't you read their documentation and try something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) for this issue like this one:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).config(function($httpProvider) { 
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope) {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                if($rootScope.yourVariable) {
                    // cancel this request
                }
            }
        }
    });
})
```

This interceptor processes every request. You can find an implementation for cancelling requests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19712323/1696578)

Answer (score 1):

To further @boindiil's answer. I tend to have it like this:

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
    .factory('httpInterceptorService', ['$q', httpInterceptorService])
    .config(['$httpProvider', interceptorConfig]);

function httpInterceptorService($q) {
    var service = {
        request: request,
        responseError: responseError
    };

    return service;

    function request(config) {
        // do some logic
        return config;
    }

    function responseError(rejection) {
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
             // they were unauthorised.
        }

        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
}

function interceptorConfig ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptorService');
}
```

Here it is more separated out. And you can see how you can easily push more interceptors into the pipeline. Obviously you can inject what ever you like into the `httpInterceptorService` like the `$rootScope`.

Just beware not create any circular dependencies.

I like what  @pankajparkar commented about, maintaining a proper call stack.

You can do this instead of using interceptors (as they are for every request).

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
    .factory('mainService', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$q', mainService])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['mainService', mainCtrl]);

function mainService($http, $rootScope, $q) {
    var service = {
        getThings: getThings
    };

    var serviceBase = '/Api/Things';

    return service;

    function getThings() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get(serviceBase).then(function (data) {
            if (data.data.someVariable == $rootScope.someVariable) {
                deferred.resolve(data.data);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(data);
            }
        }).catch(function (message) {
           deferred.reject(message);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}

function mainCtrl(mainService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.httpData = {};

    mainService.getThings().then(function (data) {
        vm.httpData = data;
    }, function (message) {
        // do something with the error.
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes that is definitely a much cleaner implementation and I would not directly use my code in production. However, I just wanted to guide `firstChild` in the right direction and gave the link to the documentation where one can find a cleaner implementation.

Comment: @boindiil yeah that's fair enough :)

Comment: @pankajparkar is the second part of my answer what you had in mind?

Comment: In our production app we have an Api service wrapping all $http calls, that checks with an interceptor in an authentication service to see if there is an auth token in the local $cookieStore, and if so, inject it into the headers prior to making the call. A service wrapper on $http calls can be very useful.

Comment: @DanielNalbach do you not just have the interceptor do this? Or are you saying you wrap the http service with you're own service layer but also have an interceptor

Comment: @CallumLinington - We wrap the http service, and also have an interceptor. There are multiple things happening in the Api wrapper, including auth stuff, load indicator determination (based on queued promises), header stripping or injection, and so on.

Comment: @DanielNalbach I tend to try and keep all cross cutting concerns in those interceptors and just use the api wrapper as a dispatcher/mediator