# Prevent request from firing in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, toastr

Is it possible to use angular interceptors to prevent the current request from firing?

For example, I have `ui-grid` that displays all orders and each order has an `Edit` and `Remove` link.  If the user clicks on either of those links and they do not have access to perform these actions I would like angular to display an `Access denied` toastr notification.

My question is, can I somehow use an angular response interceptor to look for a `HTTP 403 (Forbidden)` status result and display an `Access denied` toastr and then terminate the request?

This is the logic for the responseError interceptor:

```
var responseError = function (rejection) {
    if (rejection.status === 401) {
        return $injector.get('authService').refreshToken().then(function (response) {
            return retryHttpRequest(rejection.config).then(function (response) {
                return response || $q.when(response);
            }, function () {
                $injector.get('$state').go('logout');
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            });
        })
    }
    else if (rejection.status == 400 || rejection.status == 500) {
        notification.error("Unable to process the request due to an error!");
    }
    else if (rejection.status == 403) {
        notification.error("You do not have sufficient permissions!");
    }
    return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

Comment: see my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713753/is-it-possible-to-check-condition-before-all-http-calls-in-angular/28714186#28714186

Comment: It looks like I have already implemented by interceptor correctly.  It's my code that's designed incorrectly as I've put the logic to load an order in the wrong place.  Doh!

Comment: No worries, if you put your code on I can have look as well - up to you

Comment: I've added the code for the `responseError` if you want to take a look at it?

Comment: I wouldn't retry the request here, I would `$q.reject` with the reason of retry the request and have the logic in the service to retry the request. I think the interceptor should only deal with sending reasons rather than having more `$http` logic IMHO

Comment: I got the `retryHttpRequest` code from another website that shows how to implement seamless authentication with refresh tokens by detecting 401 errors and replaying the last request after retrieving a new refresh token.  This all works perfectly and I'm less inclined to change this bit.

Comment: Can you send me the link - i'm intrigued to see how this works!

Comment: See this [link](https://github.com/Excolo/AngularJSAuthentication) for implementing seamless refresh token requests.  This is the supporting [article](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) where I found this.