# How can I resolve a request in an AngularJS $httpProvider interceptor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I hope that I'm missing something here as this seems like it should be pretty straightforward.

I'd like to create an $httpProvider interceptor to take a look at outgoing $http requests and for some (in this case, ones that hit non existent endpoints that I'd like to fake responses for) NOT make the request but resolve it instead with some fake response data.

Here's where I am at right now:

```
myApp.factory('mockedAPIResponses', ['$q', function($q) {


 return {
    request: function(config) {
      if (/check for endpoint here/.test(config.url)) {
        // Resolve request such that it actually makes a request to the server
        var defer = $q.defer(config.timeout),
            resolvedRequest = defer.resolve({ fakeResponseData : 'foo'});
        return resolvedRequest;
      }
      return config;
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: You should move your logic into response function of the interceptor, take a look here: http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

Comment: Thanks @Dario - like i mentioned on the other answer, I certainly can do that and make it work, I'd just prefer in these cases to not make the actual XHR request at all.

Comment: Got it, check this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711550/angularjs-how-to-prevent-a-request

Answer (score 2):

### A few options

#### 1. Handle a response error:

Instead of an object with a ´request` function you should create a factory that returns a response handler in your case, since you are only interested in failed responses, you should implement and return an object with the **responseError** method:

```
function factory($q) {

   return  { 
        responseError: function(response){
              if (response.status === 404) { l
                  // handle response
                  return $q.resolve(response)
              }

              return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are unable to handle the response you should reject it so other handlers (if any) along the chain have a chance to process it

#### 2. Abort the request and handle the error:

You can abort the request in the `request()` method and then handle the aborted request in the `responseError()` method. Add some custom property or code if you want to distinguish it from regular response errors:

```
function factory($q) {

  return {

    request: function(config) {

      if (/bad/.test(config.url)) {
        config.statusText = 'Non existing path';
        config.status = 404;

        return $q.reject(config);
      }

      return config;
    },

    responseError: function(response) {

      if (response.status === 404) {
        // Handle not found errors

        response.status = 200;
        response.statusText = 'OK';
        response.data = {fake: 'data'}
        return $q.resolve(response);
      }

      return $q.reject(response);
    }
 }
```

Here is [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/E3BlmZAKIVipz2b8iWZL) that first checks the request and if it isn't valid it aborts it. Then it is handled by the `responseError()` method. You can check the network tab that no actual request is made.

#### 3. Using cache:

Yet another solution (and maybe the easiest) is to redirect the request to a cached route:

```
function factory($cacheFactory, $q) {

  var cache = $cacheFactory('fakePages');
  cache.put('cachedUrl', {fake: 'data'});

  return {

    request: function(config) {
      if (/bad/.test(config.url)) {
        config.url = 'cachedUrl';
        config.cache = cache;
      }

      return config;
    }
  }
```

}

Here is a plunk with the [cache implementation](https://plnkr.co/edit/jB7B8aWhbtjrJau1RxxV)

Comment: So I've done this and certainly WORKS, however, it seems silly for these API calls to actually MAKE the request and let it fail - in these circumstances, I'd rather not make the XHR request at all, knowing it will fail.

Comment: How would you know if the request will fail without making the request?

Comment: Checkout the update: it won't make the actual request and still handle an error response later. Just in two separate methods.

Comment: Thank you - I think option 2 there will work well. Its still seems shortsighted to me that there appears to be no mechanism to "short circuit" the request and simply resolve the promise with a stock response at the point of request (as opposed to having it jump through the hoop of being "rejected" and then handled in a separate function. But hey, code that works is code that works :)

Comment: Checkout option 3 then the `cache.put('cachedUrl', {fake: 'data'});` is your **stock response** -> you intercept a **matching** path and redirect to a url which will resolve immediately since you have a result for the route in `cache` - actual request will not be performed.